# How do I keep a cpal Stream in memory?

Tags: android, rust

I'm having general trouble with my library design in rust. I am creating a library that uses cpal.

I want to be able to call `start_stream` and `stop_stream` from the outside. When you call `start_stream` I create:

```rust
match(device.build_input_stream(... a config, a callback))
{
   Ok(stream_in) => {
      stream_in.play();
      // stream_in goes out of memory instantly and the callback will never be called
   }
   Err(...
}
```

I basically thought I could create a global state (*red flag*) where I save the stream. From there I could stop it in the future.

I tried something like:

```rust
lazy_static! {
    static ref STREAM_IN: Arc<Mutex<Option<Stream>>> = None;
}
// ... later when creating the stream I could save it here.
```

---

But that doesn't compile:

```
error[E0277]: `*mut ()` cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> src/api.rs:66:1
   |
66 | / lazy_static! {
67 | |     static ref STREAM_IN: Arc<Mutex<Option<Stream>>> = None;
68 | | }
   | |_^ `*mut ()` cannot be sent between threads safely
   |
   = help: within `Option<cpal::Stream>`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `*mut ()`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `PhantomData<*mut ()>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `cpal::platform::NotSendSyncAcrossAllPlatforms`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `cpal::Stream`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `Option<cpal::Stream>`
   = note: required for `Mutex<Option<cpal::Stream>>` to implement `std::marker::Sync`
   = note: 1 redundant requirement hidden
   = note: required for `Arc<Mutex<Option<cpal::Stream>>>` to implement `std::marker::Sync`
note: required by a bound in `Lazy`
  --> /Users/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/lazy_static-1.4.0/src/inline_lazy.rs:19:20
   |
19 | pub struct Lazy<T: Sync>(Cell<Option<T>>, Once);
   |                    ^^^^ required by this bound in `Lazy`
   = note: this error originates in the macro `__lazy_static_create` which comes from the expansion of the macro `lazy_static` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0277]: `(dyn FnMut() + 'static)` cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> src/api.rs:66:1
   |
66 | / lazy_static! {
67 | |     static ref STREAM_IN: Arc<Mutex<Option<Stream>>> = None;
68 | | }
   | |_^ `(dyn FnMut() + 'static)` cannot be sent between threads safely
   |
```

Can anybody point me to a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I created a stream which owns the audio stream. Communication is done via a channel.

something like:

```rs
let (tx, rx): (Sender<CommandRecord>, Receiver<CommandRecord>) = channel();
    let join_handle = thread::spawn(move || {
        match
            device.build_input_stream(
                &config,
                audio_in_callback,
                move |_| {},
                Some(Duration::from_secs(5))
            )
        {
            Ok(stream_in) => {
                stream_in.play().expect("Could not play stream");

                while let Ok(command) = rx.recv() {
                    match command {
                        CommandRecord::Stop => {
                             // do something to stop the stream
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Err(_) => {}
        }
    });
```